# I've found the answer to a question about 10 minutes after posting it. Do I just delete the question?

Tags: discussion

Specifically I asked this question:
[Looking for the Docker way to get just the 1st Repository Tag in "docker inspect"](https://serverfault.com/questions/990336/looking-for-the-docker-way-to-get-just-the-1st-repository-tag-in-docker-inspect)
after looking for the solution for at least an hour.
But after writing it I figured I could look at at the go-templates tag at stack overflow, and sure enough I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882553/iterate-over-a-variable-number-of-items-in-a-template-slice and it worked on the 1st try.

Am I supposed to delete the question? Answer myself? Downvote myself? 
Currently I just feel silly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Answer yourself.  It provides useful information to other people (including Future You -- I've found my own answers to SF questions via searches more than once).

Comment: +1 for `I've found my own answers to SF questions via searches` - there is nothing like feeling stupid after "I can't be the first with this problem ... strike, someone answered  it already ... oh, that was me."

Comment: Consider, insteading of feeling stupid, feeling really smart that you not only solved the problem but also had the foresight to put the solution into SF so that after you've forgotten it later you can easily find it again.